# Get the frequency domain with Goertzel Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I used this code:

```
public double goertzel(List<double> sngData, long N, float frequency, int samplerate)
{
    double skn, skn1, skn2;
    skn = skn1 = skn2 = 0;
    samplerate = this.sampleRate;
    frequency = this.freq;

    double c = 2 * pi * frequency / samplerate;
    double cosan = Math.Cos(c);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        skn2 = skn1;
        skn1 = skn;
        skn = 2 * cosan * skn1 - skn2 + sngData[i];
    }

    return skn - Math.Exp(-c) * skn1;
}
```

After use that function while processing audio data, what should i do next to get the frequency domain with that algorithm?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. The Goertzel Algorithm pulls a frequency out of signal data. The result of it is in the frequency domain. Are you trying to detect a single frequency or did you want something more like the Constant Q transform?

Comment: I think Goertzel is like FFT. So, i should get the frequency of the audio sample with that algorithm. I want to implement that goertzel Algorithm to make a song identifier (like shazam, etc).

So, i wonder how if i use the Goertzel Algorithm to get the frequency

Answer (score 1):

Goertzel algorithm is intended to find an intensity (magnitude) of some  specific frequency. Frequency is input parameter.

To get frequency spectrum of audio signal (intensity if freq. domain), you have to execute Goertzel algo for a large series of frequencies, but it would be wise to make one Fourier transform to get similar results.
One might say that Goertzel algorithm finds one sample of discrete FT.

Comment: for a large series of frequencies? like what?

Comment: like this- goertzel(20 Hz), goertzel(21 Hz), 22 Hz, 23 Hz...44099 Hz, 44100 Hz

Comment: then, after I get some values from goertzel algorithm, what should i do to make a song identifier?

Comment: It is not appropriate instrument. Fourier transform would be better. I don't know much about song identifier, but guess that the set of maximums in FT magnitude might serve as feature to recognize a song.